# Как определить цифру из многозначного числа

Tags: c#

Как определить цифру из данного числа?
Например, число 1337 состоит из 4 цифр. Как узнать вторую цифру ?

Comment: Что такое вторая цифра? Это количество десятков? Или вторая цифра слева в десятичной записи числа?

Comment: Решение уже дано.

Comment: ну так может оно неправильное, так как непонятно что вам конкретно требуется. Сломанные часы тоже два раза в день показывают правильное время

Comment: Число 1337 состоит из 4 знаков, нужно вывести второй знак. Человек давший ответ понял мою глупость и дал правильный ответ.

Comment: "Человек давший ответ понял мою глупость" - исправте "глупость" в вопросе так, чтобы его поняли все.

Comment: Исправил "глупость"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string str = 1337.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str[1]);
```

нумерация в строках такая же как и в массивах, но доступ по индексу к элементу доступен только для чтения

Answer (score 4):

Способ без превращения числа в строку (будет работать быстрее):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 534534623;
    int d = GetSecondDigit(n);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int GetSecondDigit(int k)
{
    while (k >= 100) k /= 10;
    int d = k % 10;
    return d;
}
```

Хотя, конечно, если у вас на входе строка, то проще получить второй символ по индексу (как в соседнем ответе).

Answer (score 0):

Делим без остатка на 100, затем берём остаток от деления на 10. Не понимаю, зачем вам отправили конвертацию в строку и даже отдельную функцию с циклом.

Comment: ваше предложение определит третью цифру с конца, а не вторую цифру с начала. для проверки возьмите число 12345.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите трехзначное число");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()!, out int k);
    
        if (k>999 || k<100)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Не трехзначное число!!!");
        return;
        }
        int GetSecond(int k)
        {
        while (k >= 100) k /= 10;
        int d = k % 10;
        return d;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(GetSecond(k));
```

мэйби как то так?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]