# Как получить N-ю по счёту цифру в числе?

Tags: c#

Как пример, у меня есть число 153. 2-я цифра по счёту в числе - 5.

Каким образом, зная номер цифры по счёту, можно получить её как число из другого числа?

Comment: 153 - 148, например.

Comment: Нет мне так не нужно мне нужно из числа 153 достать 5 а не так как вы предложили @Эникейщик

Comment: Опиши задачу точно. Так, как сформулировано сейчас, и доставать ничего не надо, 5 уже есть. Из 1476 что нужно было бы "достать"? А из 27?

Comment: Почему вы не приняли ни одного ответа в прошлых ваших вопросах? Все бесполезные? Если да, то почему вы не откомментировали ни одного ответа, чтобы отвечающий понял, что именно пошло не так? [Вы читали справку по StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: [Как определить цифру из многозначного числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746935/220553), или любой другой из поиска по запросу [`[c#] цифра из числа`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен неправильно. Я бы переформулировал его так: **"Как получить N-ю по счёту цифру в числе?"**. Отвечаю на переформулированный мною вопрос:

Самый простой вариант получить N-ю по счёту цифру у числа следующий:

1. Преобразовать число в строку
2. Получить по индексу нужную цифру
3. *Если необходима N-я цифра с конца строки*, то необходимо перевернуть строку
4. Преобразовать цифру из символа в число

Пример кода:

```
int number     = 153;
int digitIndex = 1; // индекс нужной цифры
int digit      = number.ToString()[digitIndex] - '0';
```

Вывод:

```
5
```

Можно для удобства написать расширение:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int GetDigit(this int number, int digitIndex) => number.ToString()[digitIndex] - '0';
}
```

Comment: **немного** *неправильно*?

Comment: @Igor много неправильно

Comment: `int digit = number / Math.Pow(10, digitIndex) % 10;` или как-то так. К черту строки :). А вообще этот вопрос здесь дубликатили уже не раз.

Comment: @aepot не спорю, так тоже можно, но мне со строками приятней

Comment: @KuzCode по производительности строки в разы медленней здесь, чем математика. И еще, если уж на то пошло `'2' - 48 == 2; // true` или `'2' - '0'`, если так понятнее.

Comment: @aepot безспорно

Comment: `'2' - 48 == 2; // true` можно переписать приятнее на `'2' - '0' == 2; // true`

Comment: Как минимум выбросить `int.Parse` можно.

Comment: @aepot ок, выбросил

Comment: `number.ToString()` дважды делаете, не надо так. Бросать исключение явно не надо, индексатор строки сделает это за вас.

Comment: @aepot такими темпами я перепишу свой ответ под ваш) Я думаю те миллисекунды того не стоят. Если кому-то они нужны просто пусть напишут `int digit = number / Math.Pow(10, digitIndex) % 10;`

Comment: Я что-то не то предложил? Речь не про математику вообще, а про то что вы бросаете `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` там, где не надо. Кроме усложнения кода оно ничего не дает, совсем.

Comment: @aepot значит не правильно вас понял

Comment: @KuzCode а вот смотрите я ещё один момент не понял почему если я запишу вот так
` public static int GetDigit(int number = 123, int digitIndex = 1) => number.ToString()[digitIndex]; ` и к примеру перменной присвою этот метод то у меня перменная будет хранить число 50, а если в конце допишу  '0' то будет 2 в отладчике посмотрел ничего не понял как оно так происходит

Comment: @whitetears https://snipp.ru/handbk/table-ascii

Comment: @whitetears потому что каждый символ расположен по пордяку и меет свой номер, и символы таким образом можно вычитать